# Firebase store custom object in database NaN error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to store my "Person" object inside the firebase database but I'm getting the same error about NaN values.

This is the Person class:

```
package HelperObjects;

import android.media.Image;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 13/03/2018.
 */
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String personImage;


    private String phoneNumber;

    public LatLng getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(LatLng address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    private LatLng address;
    private String email;

    public String getDevice_token() {
        return device_token;
    }

    public void setDevice_token(String device_token) {
        this.device_token = device_token;
    }

    private String device_token;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    private List<Job> listOfJobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
    private List<Feedback> listOfFeedbacks = new ArrayList<Feedback>();

    public Person(){

    }


    /**
     * inner class of Feedback
     */
    private class Feedback {
        private double myRate;
        private String myComment;

        public Feedback(double rate, String comment) {
            myRate = rate;
            myComment = comment;
        }
    }

    /**
     * find the current rate (average).
     * @return
     */
    public double getCurrnetFeedbackRate() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (Feedback feedback : listOfFeedbacks) {
            sum += feedback.myRate;
        }
        return  sum/listOfFeedbacks.size();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

     public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPersonImage() {
        return personImage;
    }

    public void setPersonImage(String personImage) {
        this.personImage = personImage;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public List<Job> getListOfJobs() {
        return listOfJobs;
    }

    public void setListOfJobs(List<Job> listOfJobs) {
        this.listOfJobs = listOfJobs;
    }
}
```

This is my set value method:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                accessToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        try {
                            Log.i("Response",response.toString());
                            Person person = new Person();
                            person.setEmail(response.getJSONObject().getString("email"));
                            person.setName(response.getJSONObject().getString("first_name") + " " +
                                    response.getJSONObject().getString("last_name"));
                            person.setGender(response.getJSONObject().getString("gender"));;
                            person.setDevice_token(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());;

                            mDatabase.setValue(person).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Log.i(" mDatabase.setValue", "task.isSuccessful");
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

And this is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.rubz.dvir.rubz, PID: 27287
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid value: Value cannot be NaN, Inf or -Inf.
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepf.zza(Unknown Source:200)
                      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzepf.zza(Unknown Source:141)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source:14)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source:7)
                      at com.rubz.dvir.rubz.MainCustomerActivity$3.onCompleted(MainCustomerActivity.java:189)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest$1.onCompleted(GraphRequest.java:301)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest$5.run(GraphRequest.java:1380)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest.runCallbacks(GraphRequest.java:1393)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeConnectionAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1280)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1165)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1131)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeBatchAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1115)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:1090)
                      at com.facebook.GraphRequest.executeAndWait(GraphRequest.java:984)
                      at com.rubz.dvir.rubz.MainCustomerActivity.registerNewUser(MainCustomerActivity.java:214)
                      at com.rubz.dvir.rubz.MainCustomerActivity.access$200(MainCustomerActivity.java:55)
                      at com.rubz.dvir.rubz.MainCustomerActivity$2.onComplete(MainCustomerActivity.java:147)
                      at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source:23)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Application terminated.
```

Person object holds both Feedback and Job lists, both objects are non trivial objects.
Is that's the reason?

Is there any way to store the object inside the database anyway? (e.g. with empty value for both lists?)

Thanks a lot!

Edit:

I've moved the Feedback class to a separate class, if i comment out the Feedback list the code works without errors, and i can see the data in firebase, but with the feedback list it breaks.
the weird part is that the job list is fine, and the code compiles and runs with it (although that for me they seem quite the same)

Comment: The Realtime Database does not store null values.

Comment: The lists are not null but empty. Is That possible? Could the inner class be the problem? orthe structure of the job/feedback class?

Comment: instead of storing null somewhere in firebase database using noOfChilder = 0

Comment: I'm not familiar with the noOfChilder. Can you explain what are you advising?

Comment: Keys without a value are automatically removed from the database. If you want to prevent that, store a so-called marker value (e.g. `-1` for a number) that you then recognize in your code when reading back.

Comment: Aside from that it is hard to say what's going on, since the code is quite involved and dependent on pieces we can't see (e.g. like all the values you get from the `response). Please have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Most likely your "sum/listOfFeedbacks.size();" is the culprit. What if the feedbacks size is 0? it becomes "infinite" which cannot be handled by firebase.